# What might be a blanket term for all sapient species?

Tags: aliens, language, sapience

In the far future the descendants of humanity (homo sapiens sapiens sapiens) have made contact with several intelligent aliens like.

## The Ergs

the descendants of modern humans who have modified their genome so much that they can be only be called human in the superficial scene. resembling the classic grey alien

## The Bobs

a race of green octopi like being with surprisingly humanoid faces

## Behemoths

three headed Argentinosaurus sized beings

## Beducks

a race of large insect like beings which float the their dense atmosphere

given this What might be a blanket term for all intelligent being with such varying body plans?

Comment: Can you just call them "people"?

Comment: Uh... really folks? If there *wasn't* an extant word for this, I'd agree with the closure. However, it happens there is an arguably *correct* answer. Eh, well, fortunately I answered before this was closed, so I guess it doesn't matter. (*Off topic* I'd probably agree with...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This probably belongs on english.SE, but in any case, the word you're looking for is [sophont](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sophont).

It's a <strike>real word</strike>word accepted by at least a handful of dictionaries, credited originally to Poul Anderson, that has been used in a number of SF works and means exactly what you want. No need to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: OK i just didn't know english.SE was a thing

Comment: Sapients (as in your title @icewar1908) surely works just as well & would be more immediately recognisable as appropriate to most readers I would think, abbreviated to Saps after the term is first introduced would work fine I'm sure.

Comment: @Pelinore, I think "saps" might have unfortunate connotations . I suppose "sapients" works also, but "sophonts" has built-in geek cred.